# Mapping Key Value Pair from request using RxJS and observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

My API endpoint returns json as key-value pair result. How can I map this collection to the object ICar inside .pipe method. I need observable, because I want to cache result.

Example json result:

```
{"1":"Ford", "2":"Toyota"}
```

My example code:

```
export interface ICar {
  key: string;
  carName: string;
}

getCars():Observable<ICar[]> {
   return this.httpClient.get("https://cars.com/cars")
      .pipe(
          map(???),   <--------------dont't know how to map it here
          publishReplay(1), 
          refCount()
      );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have multiple options:

- using [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
map(response => {
  const result = [];
  for(const key in response) {
    result.push({key, carName: response[key]});
  }
  return result;
}),
```

- using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
  map(response => Object.key(response).map(key => ({key, carName: response[key] }))});
```

**EDIT**

- using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
  map(response => Object.entries(response).map(([key, value])=> ({key, carName: value }))});
```

In the docs it states that there's a difference between [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) an [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), but since you use it on plain objects it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its not an array its object so you need to loop this manually

```
    for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

you need to do like this